# 2010s TV series where a journalist spots mysterious smoke but nobody believes him

Tags: story-identification, tv

The main person is a journalist and he is spotting mysterious smoke (seeing and smelling). In the smoke, there is something more to spot and he thinks it is a  connection to something.

He tries to talk to his girlfriend and to other people but nobody believes him.

The series is from the last decade and was not really successful, but it has a depth of its own (as far as I am remembering correctly).

This series has only 6 or 8 episodes and is playing in England/London.

Comment: Do you happen to remember what the mystery of the smoke turns out to be? Ghosts? Aliens? Mind-control chemicals?

Comment: maybe mind control, but i am not sure about this. the secret is not revealed in the first series (more is not available, at the time i have seen it).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the journalist is a girl and not a boy, and the series has only 3 episodes, then there's a chance it's [*Residue*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3328442/) (2015):

> The government cover-up of the causes behind a massive explosion in **a futuristic UK metropolis spur photo journalist Jennifer Preston on to search for the truth** and in the process blow open a paranormal phenomenon haunting the city.

From [this review of the second episode](https://www.themarysue.com/residue-recap-episode-2/):

> Jen, being Jen, **photographs them, then notices another black spot on the wall outside the closet**. This one’s larger and looks like a leak stain oozing tar, just like the one the baby Dementor left after infecting Benny. [...] She photographs it, reaches for it and then things get weird. **It sort of entrances her** and she gets flashes of the girl’s face and a pair of handcuffs besides some icky, bloody instruments of unspecified purpose. The black spot starts *dripping*. [...]
>
> She shows him the baby Dementors in her photos and **Jonas [her boyfriend], [...] chalks them up to camera malfunctions.**

---

Found with the Google query `scifi miniseries journalist smoke site:imdb.com`.

Comment: right. it's it. sorry for missgendering of the protagonist.

Comment: Well done! I hadn't found the right set of queries.